# How to get the numbers of data rows from sqlite table in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to get the numbers of rows returned from an sqlite3 database in python but it seems the feature isn't available:

Think of `php` `mysqli_num_rows()` in `mysql`

Although I devised a means but it is a awkward: assuming a class execute `sql` and give me the results:

```
# Query Execution returning a result
data = sql.sqlExec("select * from user")
# run another query for number of row checking, not very good workaround
dataCopy = sql.sqlExec("select * from user")
# Try to cast dataCopy to list and get the length, I did this because i notice as soon 
# as I perform any action of the data, data becomes null
# This is not too good as someone else can perform another transaction on the database 
# In the nick of time
    if len(list(dataCopy)) :
        for m in data :
            print("Name = {}, Password = {}".format(m["username"], m["password"]));
    else :
        print("Query return nothing")
```

Is there a function or property that can do this without stress.

Answer (score 15):

*Normally*, [`cursor.rowcount`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount) would give you the number of results of a query.

However, for SQLite, that property is often set to -1 due to the nature of how SQLite produces results. Short of a `COUNT()` query *first* you often won't know the number of results returned.

This is because SQLite produces rows as it finds them in the database, and won't *itself* know how many rows are produced until the end of the database is reached.

From the documentation of `cursor.rowcount`:

> Although the `Cursor` class of the `sqlite3` module implements this attribute, the database engine’s own support for the determination of “rows affected”/”rows selected” is quirky.
>
> For `executemany()` statements, the number of modifications are summed up into `rowcount`.
>
> As required by the Python DB API Spec, the `rowcount` attribute “is -1 in case no `executeXX()` has been performed on the cursor or the rowcount of the last operation is not determinable by the interface”. **This includes `SELECT` statements because we cannot determine the number of rows a query produced until all rows were fetched.**

Emphasis mine.

For your specific query, you can add a sub-select to add a column:

```
data = sql.sqlExec("select (select count() from user) as count, * from user")
```

This is not all that efficient for large tables, however.

If all you need is *one* row, use `cursor.fetchone()` instead:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid=?', (userid,))
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row is None:
    raise ValueError('No such user found')

result = "Name = {}, Password = {}".format(row["username"], row["password"])
```

Comment: `data.rowcount` returned -1

Comment: `data.COUNT()` returned `AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'COUNT'`

Comment: @Temitayo: `COUNT()` is a SQL function, not a function on the cursor.

Comment: `"select (select count() from user) as count, * from user"` using this query nearly solve the problem, although there are still some thing i need to figure out, try to pull out the first row and pull out the count without iterating on the data
`data[0]["count"]` returns `TypeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @Temitayo: No, you'd use `cursor.fetchall()` to get all rows in one go, or use `cursor.fetchone()` to just get the one result you wanted, the first row.

Comment: `data.fetchall()` return the numbers of row BUT immediately, it becomes null after one operation on `data`

Comment: @Temitayo: `data.fetchall()` returns the results *once*; store that in a local name first. You cannot call it twice and expect it to return the same data, no.

Comment: Actually, my quirk of running two queries is actually what I'm going back to, I guess like `php`, you cant get the number of rows with one handle and still process the data with the same handle. 

I have no problem with running two simultaneous queries BUT `WHAT IF ANOTHER TRANSACTION HAPPENS BEFORE THE SECOND QUERY IS CALLED` will work on it and sure paste my findings here

Comment: @Temitayo: The cursor is bound to a transaction. Another transaction won't be visible until you commit or start a new transaction.

Answer (score 13):

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(path/to/db)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from user")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print len(results)
```

len(results) is just what you want

Comment: you need to add tags to you questions, to get viewer

Comment: For a large table, this is extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 8):

Use following:

```
dataCopy = sql.sqlExec("select count(*) from user")
values = dataCopy.fetchone()
print values[0]
```

Comment: Good but i want to determine the numbers of row, before doing anything, and what what if i dont what to `fetchall`?

Answer (score 6):

When you just want an estimate beforehand, then simple use COUNT():

```
n_estimate = cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT() FROM user").fetchone()[0]
```

To get the exact number before fetching, use a locked "[Read transaction](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html#ReadTransaction)", during which the table won't be changed from outside, like this:

```
cursor.execute("BEGIN")  # start transaction
n = cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT() FROM user").fetchone()[0]
# if n > big: be_prepared()
allrows=cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user").fetchall()
cursor.connection.commit()  # end transaction
assert n == len(allrows)
```

Note: A normal `SELECT` also locks - but just until it itself is completely fetched or the cursor closes or `commit()` / `END` or other actions implicitely end the transaction ...

Answer (score 5):

I've found the select statement with count() to be slow on a very large DB. Moreover, using `fetch all()` can be very memory-intensive.

Unless you explicitly design your database so that it does not have a rowid, you can always try a quick solution

```
cur.execute("SELECT max(rowid) from Table")
n = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

This will tell you how many rows your database has.

Comment: I would _never_ use this method to determine the row count of a table. I have a table with 7,706,455 rows (as reported by `SELECT COUNT(*)...` but the max `rowid` is 96,171,095,196!

Comment: Following up on my previous comment, I actually gave a bad example, but I still say you shouldn't use this method to get the row count. Have a look at [SQLite and unique rowid … Something you really need to know](https://www.sqlabs.com/blog/2010/12/sqlite-and-unique-rowid-something-you-really-need-to-know/). If you delete rows from a table without using `VACUUM` you will get an incorrect total.

Answer (score 2):

this code worked for me:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(your_db_file)
cursor = con.cursor()
result = cursor.execute("select count(*) from your_table").fetchall() #returns array of tupples
num_of_rows = result[0][0]
```

Comment: it would produce error because  of result[0][0]:
TypeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable. You miss one line of code: result = cursor.fetchall()

Comment: Kardi Teknomo, You are right
Fixing my answer

Answer (score 2):

I did it like

```
cursor.execute("select count(*) from my_table")
results = cursor.fetchone()
print(results[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative approach here is to use fetchall to pull a column into a python list, then count the length of the list. I don't know if this is pythonic or especially efficient but it seems to work:

```
rowlist = []
c.execute("SELECT {rowid} from {whichTable}".\
          format (rowid = "rowid", whichTable = whichTable))
rowlist = c.fetchall ()
rowlistcount = len(rowlist)
print (rowlistcount)
```

Comment: For a large table, this is extremely inefficient

Answer (score 0):

The following script works:

```
def say():
    global s #make s global decleration    
    vt = sqlite3.connect('kur_kel.db') #connecting db.file
    bilgi = vt.cursor() 
    bilgi.execute(' select count (*) from kuke ') #execute sql command
    say_01=bilgi.fetchone() #catch one query from executed sql
    print (say_01[0]) #catch a tuple first item
    s=say_01[0] # assign variable to sql query result
    bilgi.close() #close query
    vt.close() #close db file
```