# Check if Sqlite3 query returns null Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I'm having some trouble forming a conditional to check if the response to my API is `null` with Python. I am using Flask and SQLite3 modules. Below is a snippet of one of my resources.

```
class Sites(Resource):
        def get(self, store):
            print('Received a request at ADDRESS for Store ' + store )
            conn = sqlite3.connect('store-db.db')
            cur = conn.cursor()
            res = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Sites WHERE StoreNumber like ' + store)
            for r in res:
                if r == 'null':
                    return('No data', 404)
                else:
                    column_names = ["StoreNumber", "Street", "StreetSecondary","City","State", "ZipCode", "ContactNumber", "XO_TN", "RelocationStatus", "StoreType", "Timezone"]
                    data = [r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6], r[7], r[8], r[9], r[10]]            
                    datadict = {column_names[itemindex]:item for itemindex, item in enumerate(data)}
                    return(datadict, 200)
```

If I make a request to a site that doesn't exist, the value returned is `null`, but none of my attempts of catching this are succeeding, so I'm wondering if my way of checking is incorrect with Python?

I've tried `r[0] == 'null'`, `r is None`, `r == 'null'`, `r == null`, and `r == Null` to no avail.

**Successful Request**

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 333
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.7.0
Date: Thu, 15 Nov 2018 15:11:03 GMT

{
  "StoreNumber": 42,
  "Street": "5000 Robinson Centre Drive",
  "StreetSecondary": "",
  "City": "Pittsburgh",
  "State": "PA",
  "ZipCode": "15205",
  "ContactNumber": "(412) 787-1330",
  "XO_TN": "(412) 249-9161",
  "RelocationStatus": "",
  "StoreType": "Dick's Sporting Goods",
  "Timezone": "Eastern"
}
```

**Request with no data (should return 404)**

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.7.0
Date: Thu, 15 Nov 2018 15:11:41 GMT

null
```

Comment: `cur.rowcount()` should have the returned number of rows. Check if it's greater than 0 (no rows).

Comment: Sadly I couldn't.

Comment: Actually @elken this won't work as ```cur.rowcount``` equals -1 whether the row count is 0 or 1.

Comment: `res.rowcount()`?

Answer (score -2):

cur.rowcount() should have the returned number of rows. Check if it's greater than 0 (no rows)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829266/how-to-get-the-numbers-of-data-row-from-sqlite3-database-in-python The first answer in this by Martin explains why that won't work.

Comment: I ran a query on an existing site where count should have been 1 (or 0) and it returned -1. I ran a query on a non-existing site where count should be 0 (or-1), and that returned -1.

Comment: A substitute for what you're expecting here would be ```len(list(cur))```